# How to forward imports from submodules in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, python-packaging

Let's assume this directory structure is mandatory for the program and cannot be changed:

```
src/
├ package_a/
│ ├ package_a/
│ │ ├ __init__.py
│ │ └ some_file_a.py
│ └ __init__.py
│
├ package_b/
│ ├ package_b/
│ │ ├ __init__.py
│ │ └ some_file_b.py
│ └ __init__.py
│
└ package_c/
  ├ package_c/
  │ ├ __init__.py
  │ └ some_file_c.py
  └ __init__.py
```

The first level of each package will never contain anything I want to import except for a same-named subpackage.

Currently, if I'm writing code in, for example, `some_file_a.py`, I have to import `some_file_b.py` like so:

```py
from package_b.package_b.some_file_b import stuff
```

**What I would like** to be able to do is instead:

```py
from package_b.some_file_b import stuff  # package_b is not repeated.
```

**How do I obtain this?**

What I've tried so far is editing `package_b/__init__.py` to `from .package_b import *` but that doesn't seem to work. I would like a solution that doesn't require me to manually write the names of the contents of subpackages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your PYTHONPATH and add the different packages so that the modules to import can be found directly. For example in VSCode, with linux terminal, assuming your workspace folder is the parent directory of src:

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {"PYTHONPATH": "${PYTHONPATH}:${workspaceFolder}/src/package_a:${workspaceFolder}/src/package_b:${workspaceFolder}/src/package_c"}
```

[EDIT] Came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615282/13339621), which is very interesting. It explains how to setup common config between users, requiring only `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`, and to install in editable mode the current project with `pip -e` option.

Comment: That would require a change for all users of the project (all devs + pipeline users). Is there a way to set PYTHONPATH for the whole project in a way that can be version-controlled? Like through pyproject.toml.

Comment: The two other options I am aware of are:  
-  create and run setup.py to install
- manually edit sys.path . But maybe best practices recommend another. I would also be interested to know.